# Filtering only a subset of a data frame

Tags: r, filtering, dplyr

I know this question is an easy one however I could not find the answer anywhere.
How to filter only a part of a data frame that respect a condition x ?

For exemple if you have:

```
df=data.frame(c1=c("A","A","B","C","B","C","C"),c2=c(1,1,4,3,6,2,6))
```

I want to get rid of the rows of the df for which c1 equals "C" that do not respect the condition c2<=3
I cannot do it like this:

```
df[df$c1=="C",]<-dplyr::filter(df[df$c1=="C",],c2<=3)
```

Of course that does not work because the replacement does not have the same number of rows. What is the easy way to do this (Preferably using `dplyr`)?
One thing that could work is to include an if statement in the filter function. Is that possible ?

Comment: read the documentation of `subset()`

Comment: `df %>% filter((c1=="C" & c2<=3)|c1!="C")`

Comment: Well that is a quick answer thank you Khashaa ! Did not think of that at all !

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Comment: And @jeremycg apart from Khashaa's trick, which is more of a clever way around the problem than of a clean solution I do not see how this question could be a duplicate of the subject you mentioned.